# How to return second register form on submition?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a page with two registration forms individual and business type and individual type form is set as default the other form is hidden, it works fine. but when I switch it to second form and click on submit button it submits second form but returns to first form after submition even on errors it return to first form.

I want it to stay on second form on errors and after submition.

Here is my php :

```
if (isset($_POST["btnRegister"])) {
    echo "Done";
}elseif (isset($_POST["btnbusiness"])) {
    echo "Done";
}
```

HTML and js codes in my page:

```js
function swapConfig(x) {
    var radioName = document.getElementsByName(x.name);
    for(i = 0 ; i < radioName.length; i++){
      document.getElementById(radioName[i].id.concat("Settings")).style.display="none";
    }
    document.getElementById(x.id.concat("Settings")).style.display="initial";
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-10 clmiddle">
    <label for="production"><b>Individual</b></label>
    <input type="radio" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="urlOptions" id="production" checked="checked" />
    <label for="development"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;Business</b></label>
    <input type="radio" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="urlOptions" id="development" />
</div>

First Form :

<div id="productionSettings" class="col-12">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> 
        <div class="col-6"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Name..." required>
            <button type="submit" name="btnRegister" class="btn btn-primary right">Send</button>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>

Second Form :

<div id="developmentSettings" style="display:none" class="col-12">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post"> 
        <div class="col-6"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Name..." required>
            <button type="submit" name="btnbusiness" class="btn btn-primary right">Send</button>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** I changed JS to php, Here is the solution.
PHP codes (which get url):

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $Aurl = explode(",",$path);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($Aurl);$i++){
      $Burl = str_replace("?", "/", trim($Aurl[$i]));
    }
$url = htmlspecialchars(basename($Burl));
$FormPostUrl = basename($path);
```

Html part :

```html
Checkbox :

<div class="col-10 clmiddle" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <label for="production"><b>Individual</b></label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("register.php"); ?>" name="checket"
        onClick="if (this.checked) { window.location = this.value; }" <?php if($url === htmlspecialchars("register.php")){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>>
    <label for="development"><b>Business</b></label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("register.php?business");?>"
        name="checket"
        onClick="if (this.checked) { window.location = this.value; }" <?php if($url === htmlspecialchars("business")){ echo 'checked="checked"';}?>>
</div> 

First Form :

<?php if($url === htmlspecialchars("register.php")){?>
<div id="productionSettings" class="col-12">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($FormPostUrl); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="col-6"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Name..." required>
            <button type="submit" name="btnRegister" class="btn btn-primary right">Send</button>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>

Second form:

<?php } elseif($url === htmlspecialchars("business")){ ?>
<div id="developmentSettings" class="col-12">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($FormPostUrl); ?>" method="post"> 
        <div class="col-6"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" placeholder="Name..." required>
            <button type="submit" name="btnbusiness" class="btn btn-primary right">Send</button>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Well obviously, you always send the form to the page with `style="display:none"` set on the second form. You will have to test something and do that to the correct form as per the current condition

Comment: @RiggsFolly You mean change `style="display:none"` in second form and set first form `style="display:none"` ?

Comment: If `$_POST["btnRegister"]` is clicked then make the correct form section visible and the other invisible

Comment: Remember to code for the initial situation when page first loads and neither form has been submitted, in that case set the page up as per your defeault situation

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for idea, I think it should be change when I switch first form to second form. with checkbox. but the problem is how :) will try.

Comment: the "how" is: using PHP to control where the `display:none` text is generated in the HTML, based on the POST variable (if any is set).

Comment: @ADyson I dont get what you mean, is it possible to do it with php ? can you give an example please. thanks

Comment: Well, you can see how you've used PHP inside the HTML to set data like the form's "action" attribute? Same basic idea, use PHP to control whether `display:none` is added to your divs or not. Use an `if` statement (or a ternary operator might be neater syntax in the context) to make the decision about what to echo. Example answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP to control whether `display:none` is added to your divs or not. Use an `if` statement (or a ternary operator might be neater syntax in the context) to make the decision about what to echo. Since the default is to display the production settings form, we only need to check whether the other form has been submitted or not, in order to know whether to change that.

e.g. something like this (untested):

```
<input type="radio" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="urlOptions" id="production" <?php echo (isset($_POST["btnRegister"]) ? "" : 'checked="checked"'); ?> />
```

and

```
<input type="radio" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="urlOptions" id="development" <?php echo (isset($_POST["btnRegister"]) ? 'checked="checked"' : ""); ?> />
```

and

```
<div id="productionSettings" class="col-12" <?php echo (isset($_POST["btnbusiness"]) ? "style='display:none'" : ""); ?>>
```

and

```
<div id="developmentSettings" class="col-12" <?php echo (isset($_POST["btnbusiness"]) ? "" : "style='display:none'"); ?>>
```

---

P.S. Unless you've massively simplified these forms for the purpose of your example, they appear to be basically identical. It's questionable whether you actually need two separate forms at all. The only difference appears to be the choice between "individual" and "business" - that could be handled by a single form with a radio button to choose the type, which would then simplify how you handle the postback as well, and reduce the amount of duplicated code and HTML. Of course if you're actually capturing more distinct fields for these forms than you've shown, then these remarks don't really apply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was about to change `<input type="radio" onchange="swapConfig(this)" name="urlOptions" id="production" 
      <?php if (isset($_POST["urlOptions"])) { echo 'checked="checked"'}?> />`. I will try your code too and let you know. thanks again.

Comment: You're right actually you would also need to apply a change like you're suggesting so that the radio button has the correct value when the page loads. That's required as well as my changes. Not sure where you think `$_POST["urlOptions"]` is going to be coming from though? neither of your forms submit that value - the radio button is outside any form. You need to read the value of the register button, as I've done in my example.

Comment: But also please see my P.S. - do you actually need two forms at all here?

Comment: I need both forms in same page, I think its beter to change `checked="checked"` with js codes, so when it switches to second form it can set second form checked as default immideately instead of clicking button, but I dont understand js much.

Comment: _" I think its beter to change checked="checked" with js codes"_ ...you're already doing that, that's fine for after the page has loaded and the user clicks it, but here we're dealing with setting up the page correctly so it looks right when initially loaded. It's a separate problem, for which you need PHP so it can make the initial HTML correct before the browser tries to display it.

Comment: _"I need both forms in same page"_ ...why _exactly_? That was my question. Is it because in reality they are more complex than you've shown here? Or something else?

Comment: You're right I will change forms in two pages simple, better than dealing with complex codes. I changed profile page. thanks

Comment: Well one _page_ is fine, it was two _forms_ that I was talking about. Putting two forms in two pages doesn't really address the issue. And you still haven't answered my question about why two separate forms is actually necessary, when the only seem to have one field different (which could be handled by a radio button). Thanks for changing the profile though, much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried with php codes in your answer and my suggestion too but still loads first form when I click the button in second form because of js. so I need to do changes in js code. any suggestion for that ? loads first form even with second check box checked.

Comment: Unless you are deliberately running the swapConfig code (or some equivalent code) when the page loads then the JS should not affect anything. From what you've shown it doesn't get triggered until the user selects a radio button.

Comment: And you still haven't answered the question about 2 forms.